# mysql get avg value on a a field that needs to be modified first based on results of a case statement

Tags: mysql, case, average

I am attempting to get the weekly average of a field "weight" over a specified date range using mySQL.  The spanner in the works here is that the weight is stored in Kg in some records and lbs in others.  There is also a flag in the table (unitsMode) that specifies whether the weight is a metric or imperial one.  So I need to perform a calculation on the weight field based upon the unitsMode - am doing this using CASE.   But now I can't do the average, or rather do not know "where" to do the average.  Am doing this as a stored procedure, current code below:

```
PROCEDURE `weeklyweighttest`(IN uId INTEGER, IN rangeStart DATE, IN rangeEnd DATE)
BEGIN
select weight,unitsMode, floor(DATEDIFF(entryDate,curdate())/7) as weeks_ago, CASE unitsMode
          WHEN 1 THEN truncate((weight/2.2),2)
          WHEN 0 THEN truncate(weight,2)
         END  AS calcWeight
 FROM `mydatabasetable` WHERE userId=uId AND entryDate >= rangeStart AND entryDate <= rangeEnd
 GROUP BY floor(DATEDIFF(entryDate,curdate())/7);
END
```

Many thanks in advance for any input here

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `AVG` around the case statement:

```
 AVG(CASE unitsMode
         WHEN 1 THEN truncate((weight/2.2),2)
         WHEN 0 THEN truncate(weight,2)
     END) AS calcWeight
```

Comment: Ahhh, looks so simple...and bleeding obvious.  I will run some tests and let you know!  Thanks Terje